# Retrieve data from object in php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

After retrieving `$competitors` from MySQL successfully with the following distance query...

```
$competitors = DB::table('homes')
    -> select(array('*', DB::raw('SQRT(POW('.$Eastings.' - `Eastings`,2) + POW('.$Northings.' - `Northings`,2)) AS distance')))
    -> having('distance', '<', $micromarket_size)
    -> get();
```

... I'm trying to retrieve the data I get back, specifically if, fees and occupancy parameters. I tried to access the data by doing something like:

```
$competitors->id[2];
```

But get the error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

I then thought I would loop through all competitors:

```
foreach ($competitors as $competitor) {
    $i=0;
    $id[$i]           = $competitor->id;
    $fees[$i]         = $competitor->minSingleCareFee;
    $occupancy[$i]    = $competitor->Average_Occupancy;
    $i = $i + 1;
};
```

And then try the following:

```
echo $id[2];
```

But I still get an error. Any help appreciated!

Comment: `$competitors->id[2];` doesnt make sense. From database you get a string or a number - not an array. And what about `$id[2]`? Are you sure there is `id=2` in your return?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($competitors);
echo '</pre>';

 $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
 $last_query = end($queries);
 echo $last_query;
 die();
```

And run the sql query in phpmyadmin or anyother

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

So I figured out I could simply access the properties by going `$competitors[i]->id` instead of `$competitors->id[i]`;

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `$competitors` is a collection so you may loop it like this:

```
foreach($competitors as $competitor) {
    echo $competitor->id; // use other properties like same way
}
```